# PyQtGraph plot incorrectly displayed on Qt MainWindow

Tags: qt, python-3.x, graph, pyqt, pyqtgraph

So I'm trying to get PyQtGraph to plot a graph in a GUI that I am developing (you can check it here https://github.com/allg18/MuonAquisitionTool , I am using Python3 and PyQt4). 
However, when I add the plotwidget to the groupbox in the MainWindow, it always stays tiny. The plotgraph didn't expand to ocuppy the whole of the groupbox.

```
class MainWindow2(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow2, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.

        self.setupUi(self)

        """Booting up the Graphics"""
        self.preview_plot = pg.PlotWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.preview_plot.adjustSize()
        self.data1 = numpy.random.normal(size=300)
        self.curve1 = self.preview_plot.plot(self.data1)
```

In which the groupBox_2 is the place where I want to put it within the MainWindow.
As you can see I also tried to put a "adjust_size" there. I also tried:

```
self.preview_plot.resize(500, 500)
```

And this actually worked, it was the only way I got a size different from the one in the image

UPDATE:
I tried the adding the following line, but this did again not change the size of the graph widget...

```
self.graph.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

[image: Print-Screen of the GUI Running.]

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to position the widgets yourself, this is hard and error prone. Qt has a layout mechanism to do this for you. You can read about it [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html)

I cannot fix your example because it is not complete, I don't have the `QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow` classes (in the future please make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). However, there is probably some groupbox layout to which you can add your plot widget with `addWidget`.

Comment: What do you mean by positioning the widgets myself? I just set the parent widget with "self.preview_plot = pg.PlotWidget(self.groupBox_2)"... Then I tried different commands, but the only one that did anything to the image size was the "resize" I did. However, "resize(self.preview_plot.sizeHint())" did nothing as well.

Comment: I meant don't do any explicit resizing or positioning. Just use the layout mechanism.